# How to match username which is enclosed in special chars

Tags: regex

I try to match the username of users on [YouNow](https://www.younow.com) from a specific field.

I extracted this html, I try to extract the username **_You Won**

```
"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t14\n\t\t\t\t\t\t_You Won\n\t\t\t\t\t"
```

This is my regex attempt:

```
(\d+)[\\n\\t]+([\W\w]+[^\\n\\t"$])
```

This worked fine, first I match a number which is the level, then I match the username. However, if the username ends with either `t` or `n` then it does not get the last letter. So user **game 1n** would get cut down to **game 1**

Does someone know how I can fetch the username correctly?

**Play it:**
https://regex101.com/r/j8rufa/2

Comment: Note that regex101 treats your string as literal string, so `\n` is literal, not a newline - so a solution working with that string is probably not working in your real word application and vice versa.

Comment: Thats not a problem, I made sure that it works also vice versa, I just need the correct regex for this string, but I think there is much room for improvement, since im a beginner with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Positive Lookahead at the end instead of `[^\\n\\t"$]`.

Your code will be:

```
(\d+)[\\nt]+([\W\w]+(?=\\n\\t))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/j8rufa/4

You can also use Positive Lookbehind to further enhance the code to ensure that the whole name is matched. For example, if the name is something like `t_You Won`, it will be matched without any issues:

```
(\d+)[\\nt]+(?<=\\t)([\W\w]+(?=\\n\\t))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/j8rufa/6

Comment: You can shorten `[\\n\\t]` to `[\\tn]` - and I hope you will never face  user name starting with t, e.g. tnt. There will be more issues if stuff is following after the username.

Comment: @EdwardBlack My pleasure :)

Comment: @SebastianProske Thanks for the suggestion. I updated the code to shorten it. +1

Comment: @SebastianProske ah you are correct, if it starts with tnt then it does not work again. But we are a big step further now at least.

Comment: @EdwardBlack No worries, I updated my code to capture names that starts with tnt as well.

Comment: @Ibrahim, great, now it should fully work! :) I appreciate that you took your time to help!! I've learned alot thanks to you